# In IOS, how to use CGContextClearRect to clean up a Circle Area?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

If I want to clear a rectangle area, I can use this

```
CGContextClearRect(aContext, rectangle);
```

so how can I clean up a Circle Area by using `CGContextClearRect`?

Comment: you can try drawing a circle with color set to background colour on the top.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to draw an arc to clip with...

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 
CGContextAddArc(aContext, 50, 50, 50, 0.0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextClip(aContext); 
CGContextClearRect(aContext, rectangle);
```